# Setting acceptance threshold for usability evaluation outcome

Tags: usability, ux-field, usability-study, heuristics

I am working on a framework to evaluate our products usability against our product design tenets which are nothing else than 10 usability (N&N) heuristics in our own words. The goal is to identify which of the usability areas we're not doing great. That said, we have 8 heuristics covering specific usability areas. There will be a checklist in each of the heuristics to be scored against and at the end we will have a percentage as the score for each one.

My question is, how do you know what each score means? Is 70% good or bad? How do I set the threshold? Also, how do you weight each of the heuristics in order of importance? Surely it's more important for a website to, i.e., always provide system feedback and in a timely fashion rather than for it to be pretty looking.

I wonder if you have any advice? I hope all this makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to use a kind of 'unit tests'? I mean use a set of parameters which should be achieved all, otherwise product will be evaluated as bad. So, product should have 100% to be counted as good. Will it help you if you know that omelet which you are coocking is 70% good? It looks pretty fine (value is 70%) but have to much salt in it (0%). Should you bring it to your customer as it is 70% good? I mean that heuristic may have threshold inside it, e.g. salt level, but as a result you need to have 'acceptable'/'unacceptable' scale.

Answer (score 0):

Why create your own metric? If you use an "off the shelf" one where the psychometrics are already established and you don't have to worry about weights and cut off scores?

Or do a pass/fail heuristic evaluation where the heuristic is present or not. I think pushing for the percentages and cutoff may be what is confusing you. Check out this article: https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/heuristic-evaluation.html